# Can't get `dispatchEvent` to fire in GHCJS

Tags: javascript, haskell, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

The goal is to get `window.addEventListener("popstate", ...` to fire from an event dispatched from GHCJS code.

---

## Tried so far

GHCJS.DOM doesn't work

```hs
w <- currentWindowUnchecked
e <- newPopStateEvent "popstate" Nothing
dispatchEvent_ w e
```

Language.Javascript.JSaddle doesn't work

```hs
e <- newPopStateEvent "popstate" Nothing
jsg "window" ^. jsf "dispatchEvent" (toJSVal e)
```

FFI doesn't work

```hs
foreign import javascript unsafe "window.dispatchEvent($1)" dispatchIt :: JSVal -> JSM ()

e <- newPopStateEvent "popstate" Nothing
dispatchIt =<< toJSVal e
```

### Debugging output

This does work:

```hs
e <- newPopStateEvent "popstate" Nothing
w <- currentWindowUnchecked
jsg "console" ^. js2 "log" (toJSVal e) (toJSVal w)
```

And produces and interesting result

[image]

As you can see the `JSVal`s are correct, and we can run the command in the JavaScript console.

### Latest attempt

Then I discovered that if I throw an error right after `dispatchEvent`, it fires.

```hs
foreign import javascript unsafe "window.foo()" foo :: JSM ()

w <- currentWindowUnchecked
e <- newPopStateEvent "popstate" Nothing
dispatchEvent_ w e
liftJSM foo
```

This causes the expected result with `dispatchEvent_`, but obviously wont do, as it causes a runtime error.

So I thought it might be a `syncPoint`

Still no dice

```hs
!e <- newPopStateEvent ("popstate" :: Text) Nothing
!() <- dispatchEvent_ w e                                                                                     
liftJSM GHCJS.DOM.syncPoint
```

---

## Run the code

You can try this out for yourself

```sh
git clone -b crud-example https://gitlab.com/fresheyeball/Shpadoinkle.git
cd Shpadoinkle
./examples/servant-crud/run-crud.sh
```

open `localhost:8080` in your browser, and click on the word `"ECHO"`.

Relevant code:

https://gitlab.com/fresheyeball/Shpadoinkle/blob/crud-example/router/Shpadoinkle/Router.hs#L100
https://gitlab.com/fresheyeball/Shpadoinkle/blob/crud-example/examples/servant-crud/View.hs#L43